# Can't use both fig.pos and out.width/height in knitr?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I am using the bookdown package to build my pdf. Here is my `_output.yml`:

```r
## Here to create the pdf
bookdown::pdf_book:
  extra_dependencies: ["float"]
  toc: true
  template: _assets/template.tex
  mainmatter: true
  includes:
    in_header: _assets/preamble.tex
  latex_engine: lualatex
  keep_tex: yes
  citation_package: natbib
```

When I use only `fig.pos = "!H"` or `out.height="75%"`, the knitting works.

However, I'd like to use both `fig.pos = "!H"` and  `out.height="75%"` (for instance `{r fig, fig.cap="Caption", out.height="75%", fig.pos = "!H"}`) but when I do so, I have:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.
```

I checked and the package `float` is correctly installed.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that prevents `fig.pos` and `out.height` from being used a the same time. If I evaluate the code below:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: latex_fragment
---

```{r fig, fig.cap="Caption", out.height="75%", fig.pos = "!H"}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+ theme_minimal()
```
````

I get the following latex output:

```
\begin{figure}[!H]
\includegraphics[height=0.75\textheight]{TestX_files/figure-latex/fig-1} \caption{Caption}\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
```

Which is what you'd expect with the options given (note the `0.75\textheight` and the `[!H]`)

The error comes from the package `float` not being available. To properly produce a pdf with `fig.pos` options, add the following:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document :
    extra_dependencies: ["float"]
---
```

as explained [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-placement.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but no, it didn't work. I tried both to write `extra_dependencies: ["float"]` or to write `\usepackage{float}` directly in my .tex template but I still have the same message